# Special Kind of Metric

Tags: differential-geometry

What types of consequences can generate a metric that does not allow spheres?

..I mean that there isn't a parametrization for the sphere, because the metric does not allow it.

In particular if I have this metric $ds^2 =E∗(du^2 +dv^2)$ with $E>0$ and harmonic...the spheres do not exist, because in this metrics the "totally umbilical" surfaces have the second fundamental form as $e,f:=0,g:=e$...with this second fundamental form and considering E a harmonic function, the only possible immersion in $R^3$ is the plane. 
Therefore in this metric do not exists the spheres...Now my question is, what types of possible consequence can generate?

Comment: Not sure I understand: A metric whose Gaussian curvature is non-constant certainly does not come from an isometric immersion of part of a sphere. Is that what you mean by "does not allow spheres"? Separately, a positive harmonic function on $\mathbf{R}^{2}$ is constant, so the resulting metric is flat, hence not a sphere, as you say. But "positive harmonic function" seems like a very strong hypothesis compared to the not particularly strong conclusion "is not part of a sphere". Again, maybe I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Dear Andrew, thanks for your reply! With "does not allow spheres" I mean that with this metric, the only isometric immersion for "totally umbilic" surfaces must given by PDE $2*c^2*E^3=(E_u)^2+(E_v)^2$ (this PDE is given by Gauss-Codazzi equation), the solution to the PDE for $E>0$ is $c=0$, in other words the isometric immersion is a plane.

Comment: Now on the basis of this, the space that induces this type of metric is a space that does not allow the spheres..what can this mean? What kind of consequences may involve??